# Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii() Magento 2.3.1 with PHP 7.2

Tags: email, deprecated, php-7.2, magento-2.3

I'm using Magento 2.3.1 with PHP 7.2, facing error while creating customers account at admin end.

Found some sources on the internet to degrade PHP version.

Is there any other option available without degrading PHP 7.2?

Log:

main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated in /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 560

idn_to_ascii() at Line 560:

```
return (idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact issue after upgrading the PHP version of the server to 7.3.

Initially, the issue was with the Zend framework like yourself, but after an upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 (in an attempt to correct the problem), an identical error was thrown for the newer Laminas.

I tried a number of solutions, including downgrading guzzle from 6.5.3 to 6.5.2, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61596343/9667652

It seems the only solution is to downgrade PHP to 7.1. The issue continues even with PHP 7.2. I downgraded to PHP 7.1 and emails are now sending.

**EDIT:** As per comment by @user125661, it's important to note that PHP 7.1 is no longer supported:

> PHP 7.1 has reached End of Life. To maintain PCI compliance, Magento should not be run on unsupported software. Installing from GitHub will no longer work with Magento 2.3.4/PHP 7.1. The only way to install 2.3.4 with PHP 7.1.x is with Composer. Magento recommends using PHP 7.3

See: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php

This issue has been encountered repeatedly but is not able to be reproduced reliably, as documented here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19795

Looks as though the most likely reason for the issue is servers running CentOS 6, where CentOS 7 is needed: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19795#issuecomment-486432245

Best bet is to get your server onto CentOS 7, but where this is not possible, it seems the only workaround is downgrading to PHP 7.1.

Comment: Please note: "PHP 7.1 has reached End of Life. To maintain PCI compliance, Magento should not be run on unsupported software. Installing from GitHub will no longer work with Magento 2.3.4/PHP 7.1. The only way to install 2.3.4 with PHP 7.1.x is with Composer. Magento recommends using PHP 7.3"

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

So I don't think your advice could be accepted as an answer.

Comment: @user125661 I am aware of the conflict, but should have thought to include more references. I've updated my answer with more detail to reflect the issue and its resolution.