# Laravel Deprecated Error: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel version is 6.

My registration form is not working on live server but it's working good for localhost.

When I hit register button, it throws this exception.

```
idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated
```

It's pointing out to my `RegisterController.php` on line 114.

```
$this->validator($request->all())->validate();
```

and this line vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php:35

```
? idn_to_ascii($uri->getHost(), $options)
```

RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'register_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:8'],
            'register_email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
            'register_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'user_type'=> ['required','in:user,company'],
            'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required','captcha'],

        ]);
        $validator->setAttributeNames([
            'register_email' => 'email',
            'register_password' => 'password',
        ]);

        return $validator;
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
      $user = User::create([
          'name' => $data['register_name'],
          'email' => $data['register_email'],
          'password' => Hash::make($data['register_password']),
          'user_type' =>$data['user_type'],

      ]);

      $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

      return $user;
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: what does this do? `$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`
can you show the whole controller method

Comment: @lewis4u Thanks for your time. I just updated my question. Please refresh to see my controller code

Comment: @lewis4u Any update ?

Comment: Maybe you can slightly update Guzzle to the next version?

Comment: Oh it seems you are using the wrong Request class. Check the use statement to be sure that your Request is from `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: it is happening with guzzle and php 7.2 7.3.  but on my local homestead its worked

Comment: @ShahidChaudhary Did you find out the solution ?
What should I do ?

Comment: https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/issues/163

Comment: I have written my solution, you can check the answer by @Ashwani Garg

Comment: I've just had this problem with php 7.2 on my live server. Updating via cPanel MultiPHP Manager to php 7.4 has fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have php7.3 on my server. and I was getting the same error. 
**But hurrey, I fixed my problem.**

When we install guzzle in our Laravel app using this command

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

It install lower version of guzzle than ^7.
and to fix this problem, we need latest guzzle version, which is ^7.0 at the time of writing this post.

So, there is the solution.

Edit your composer.json file on the server.
and update your guzzle version like this.

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
```

then run the command on your server terminal.

```
composer update
```

That's it.

If you don't have server ssh connected to your pc, you can update your local project and re-upload the whole vendor directory.

Comment: I had the same problem. I updated my guzzle version as you suggested, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Mohit - What is php version on server?

Comment: it's 7.3 on server and 7.4 on my local system.

Comment: Are you using Laravel version 7.*  ?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. Laravel version is 7.9.2

Comment: @AshwaniGarg 
I' m using another package that is "laravel/socialite" and it's version is 4.3.2 and it's only works with only Guzzle version 6. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause to your problem is simple:

Missmatch between PHP versions, on your local dev machine you have probably a different PHP version than the one on the server!

Comment: This error is about PHP version 7.2. I already knew it. 
I upgraded my xampp to PHP 7.4 and then re-import the project on live server that has version 7.3. It's still not fixed.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do on local server before deploying my project to live?

Answer (score 0):

> SOLVED

I faced the same issue: on local windows pc php `7.2.30`, guzzle `6.5.3` working fine. but same versions on the server throws this above error with exact line numbers. downgrading guzzle `6.5.2` solved the issue onto the server. 
what I suspect is intl behaviour on both the side might be different.

intl on local machine:

```
version | 1.1.0
-- | --
ICU version | 64.2
ICU Data version | 64.2
ICU TZData version | 2019a
ICU Unicode version | 12.1
```

intl on server:

```
version | 1.1.0
-- | --
ICU version | 4.2.1
```